# Make tree from mathematical expression by std::regex

Tags: c++, regex

Programm get string like:`VARIABLE=EXPRESSION.`

where `VARIABLE` is some letters and numbers, starting letter
and `EXPRESSION` is mathematical expression that can include:

```
1) + or *
2) ( or )
3) numbers (for example, 5; 3.8; 1e+18, 8.41E-10)
4) another names of variables.
```

I need to turn this into the tree (just in memory) using **one** regular exprassion.
How can i do this?
Was proposed method:

1. search for = out of ()
2. search for + out of ()
3. search for * out of ()
4. if somethig found - break expression in 2 parts, else we got number or variable.

Looks pretty simple, but i can't create this expressions.
I'm alse found how to put conditional operator into regular expression.
Mostly, i just need 3 regular exprassions for =, + and *.
Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8R12.png

Comment: This is not possible. Regular expressions cannot deal with nested parentheses.

Comment: It's don't needed. Regular expression just have to find right sign and get 2 parts of original mathematical expression for next iteration of recursion.

Comment: In example this expression must find "=", so i can get "hurrdurr" and "(1e+18+a*b)+10*(2*c)+d" after and put both string in the same procedure.

Comment: And then what? You still have to deal with the parentheses. And when you find the correct mechanism to do that, you'll find you suddenly don't need the regular expressions.

Comment: After i get, for example, "(2*c)" i can just use standard functions if C++ to make "2*c" and after use regex again.

Comment: And then you have to deal with the operator precedence, and parenthesis nesting, and ... You're using the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: Yes, i know. I should do it this way because it is in condition of that task.

Comment: If 'because it is in condition of that task' means that someone else has told you to do it this way, you need to show them these comments and answers. Three different people have told you. You've been given wrong information and an impossible assignment. Say so.

Comment: You should also look up the Dijkstra *Shunting-yard algorithm* (1960) as an alternative to recursive descent.

Comment: Regular expressions cannot deal with arbitrary arithmetic expressions with parentheses. That's a mathematical fact. The task as you represent it is impossible. Either you are missing some important information in the assignment, or whoever wrote it forgot to put it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by n.m., regular expressions can't deal with nested parentheses. However there are simple alternatives that can parse nested parenthesis, such as [recursive descent parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser#C_implementation).

Example:

```
enum TokenType
{
    TTId,
    TTNumber,
    TTPlus,
    TTMinus,
    TTTimes,
    TTDivide,
    TTLParen,
    TTRParen,
    TTEndOfInput
};

TokenType token = TTEndOfInput;
string tokenValue;
int peekChar();
void nextChar();
void error(string msg); // doesn't return
Value *createConstant(string value);
Value *createReadVariable(string name);
Value *createAdd(Value *l, Value *r);
Value *createSubtract(Value *l, Value *r);
Value *createMultiply(Value *l, Value *r);
Value *createDivide(Value *l, Value *r);
Value *createNegate(Value *l, Value *r);

Value *expression();

void getToken()
{
    token = TTEndOfInput;
    tokenValue = "";
    if(peekChar() == EOF)
        return;
    if(isalpha(peekChar()))
    {
        while(isalnum(peekChar()))
        {
            tokenValue += (char)peekChar();
            nextChar();
        }
        token = TTId;
        return;
    }
    if(isdigit(peekChar()) || peekChar() == '.')
    {
        while(isdigit(peekChar()))
        {
            tokenValue += (char)peekChar();
            nextChar();
        }
        if(peekChar() == '.')
        {
            tokenValue += (char)peekChar();
            nextChar();
            while(isdigit(peekChar()))
            {
                tokenValue += (char)peekChar();
                nextChar();
            }
            if(tokenValue == ".")
                error("missing digit");
        }
        if(peekChar() == 'e')
        {
            tokenValue += (char)peekChar();
            nextChar();
            if(peekChar() == '+' || peekChar() == '-')
            {
                tokenValue += (char)peekChar();
                nextChar();
            }
            if(!isdigit(peekChar()))
                error("missing digit");
            while(isdigit(peekChar()))
            {
                tokenValue += (char)peekChar();
                nextChar();
            }
        }
        token = TTNumber;
        return;
    }
    switch(peekChar())
    {
    case '+':
        token = TTPlus;
        nextChar();
        return;
    case '-':
        token = TTMinus;
        nextChar();
        return;
    case '*':
        token = TTTimes;
        nextChar();
        return;
    case '/':
        token = TTDivide;
        nextChar();
        return;
    case '(':
        token = TTLParen;
        nextChar();
        return;
    case ')':
        token = TTRParen;
        nextChar();
        return;
    default:
        error("invalid charater");
    }
}

Value *topLevel()
{
    Value *retval;
    switch(token)
    {
    case TTId:
        retval = createReadVariable(tokenValue);
        getToken();
        return retval;
    case TTNumber:
        retval = createConstant(tokenValue);
        getToken();
        return retval;
    case TTLParen:
        getToken();
        retval = expression();
        if(token != TTRParen)
            error("expected )");
        getToken();
        return retval;
    case TTMinus:
        getToken();
        return createNegate(topLevel());
    default:
        error("unexpected token");
    }
}

Value *mulDiv()
{
    Value *retval = topLevel();
    while(token == TTTimes || token == TTDivide)
    {
        TokenType operation = token;
        getToken();
        Value *rhs = topLevel();
        if(operation == TTTimes)
        {
            retval = createMultiply(retval, rhs);
        }
        else // operation == TTDivide
        {
            retval = createDivide(retval, rhs);
        }
    }
    return retval;
}

Value *addSub()
{
    Value *retval = mulDiv();
    while(token == TTPlus || token == TTMinus)
    {
        TokenType operation = token;
        getToken();
        Value *rhs = mulDiv();
        if(operation == TTPlus)
        {
            retval = createAdd(retval, rhs);
        }
        else // operation == TTMinus
        {
            retval = createSubtract(retval, rhs);
        }
    }
    return retval;
}

Value *expression()
{
    return addSub();
}

void error(string msg)
{
    cerr << "error : " << msg << endl;
    exit(1);
}

int main()
{
    getToken();
    Value *expressionTree = expression();
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You meen, i can't find 3rd "+" in "(1e+18+a*b)+10*(2*c)+d" by regular exprassion?

Comment: @user3206223 Thats not what he said at all, but why would you want to do that? That's not how you parse expressions.